# SharePoint Clock

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have embedded in a SharePoint content editor:

```
<embed src="http://www.clocklink.com/clocks/5004p-blue.swf?DateFormat=yyyy / mm / dd DDD&TimeFormat=hh:mm:ss TT&Place=Boston&TimeZone=USA_Boston" width="192" height="16" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

I have serious problems editing this page and am only able to use the page when i enable the content. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated :D!

Comment: Appending the foll. to your page url will open the Web Part Page Maintenance: ?contents=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending the foll. to your page url will open the Web Part Page Maintenance: ?contents=1

Answer (score 1):

Edit the html of the CEWP ad paste it into a text editor. Remove the html from the CEWP. Save the html in the editor as a .html file and upload it to a document library. Edit the CEWP and point the Content Link to the file you just uploaded.

Putting html and/or script directly into a CEWP is possible on web part pages, not on wiki or publishing pages. Linking to external files is the cleaner method. You can also re-use (link to) the same external file in many other CEWPs on other pages.